# How to use "element of" compressed for two contrains

Tags: notation

I'm not sure if I understand the "element of" notation correctly and thus have two questions.
So, let's say there are two functions: f1(x) and f2(x).
I would like to define the element of those two functions.
Both function shall only return positive real numbers higher than zero
Also I would like to "compress" the statement as one equation.
Currently I have the following notation:

```
{f1(x), f2(x)} ∈ { ℝ | >0 }
```

Is that notation correct and does it force the conditions as I described?

Comment: That is not correct usage of "element of".   There is no need for compression or formality. Help your reader by simply saying _in words_ that the values of both functions are positive real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Just use "maps" and "mapsto" notation for defining functions and define the range to be $\mathbb{R}^+$